# Estimated earnings admob dropped to 0

Tags: android, admob, impressions

I have an Android application in Google Play and I show a banner at the bottom of the screen.

I uploaded the application three days ago, until now the estimated earnings have increased but today I got up and saw that the banner has been shown 55 times but my estimated earnigs have dramatically decrased to 0.

[image: Estimated earnings vs impressions]

What is this due to? Is this a sign that I'm doing something wrong and Google is penalizing me?

Comment: How many click on the banner did you received ?

Comment: @SimonePessotto It received 0 clicks and the day before there were 4 clicks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is not about programming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, depends!

How many click did you received today ?

55 impressions aren't enough to make statistics. Check the clicks. It's normal if you have 1-2 click/day that someday maybe nobody click the banner

AdMob pay only for the clicks, not for the impressions.

Comment: It received 0 clicks and the day before there were 4 clicks.

Comment: So, it's normal! Because AdMob pay only for cliks not for impression

Comment: 4 clicks aren't enough to make statistics. There are too many variables that make an user click the banner. it's all fine, wait and in the next day some clicks arrives :)

Comment: Thank you all, I will continue waiting to see if it improves but knowing that Google is not angry with me it's enough for today.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter not for the SO. But I will answer. In Admob money paying for only clicks (not impressions). In addition, the algorithms all the time looking for cheat and the exact amount of money earned will be known only at the end of the month. "Projections" will be working with a lot of impressions. (1-2k) 200 to impressions is still very low. Do not worry: everything is fine.

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you very much, this was getting me very nervous. I don't want to loose my account 3 days after created.

Comment: If you do not click your ad, do not worry. (probably)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I feel the need to add this.

there is CPM bids, which are paid per impression and CPC bids which are paid with clicks.

I have 30k impression per day with my banner ad.

Most are CPC bids. But if im correct CPC bids also have CPM revenue.